# How do I hide a particular HTML element that contains a specific word from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Suppose, I want to hide any HTML element that displays the word "foo", from Facebook newsfeed.

So far, I have learnt that I must create an extension using JavaScript that runs in the background that detects presence of a certain word and hides the whole post.

Basically, I want to understand how ad-block extensions that run on browsers are implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

Use `querySelectorAll` to get the specific elements or you can use more specific selector like id or class to target the absolute element. Itereate through the collection & check the `textContent` or `innerHTML`.

You can hide it directly changing the style property or add a class to that element to hide it

```
var getAllDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div');
getAllDiv.forEach(function(item) {

  if (item.textContent.trim() == 'John') {
    console.log(item.textContent)
    item.style.display = 'none'
  }

})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/7hp0gw4g/)